# Error when using to_categorical in tflearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I use tflearn to train my dataset, and I use `tflearn.data_utils.build_hdf5_image_dataset` to creat a hdf5 dataset. But when I try to use `to_categorical` to convert class vector， it shows

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/data_utils.py", line 42, in to_categorical

Y[np.arange(len(y)),y] = 1.

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (50000,) (50000,10)
```

Now I doubt about it the problem of dataset, I try to make the dataset by cifar-10 iamges and it showed this error again. This is my code, please help me check it. Thanks.

```
h5train_file = 'data/cifartrain.h5'
h5test_file = 'data/cifartest.h5'

dataset_file = 'data/cifar/train/'
datatest_file = 'data/cifar/test/'
tflearn.data_utils.build_hdf5_image_dataset(dataset_file, image_shape=(32, 32), mode='folder', output_path=h5train_file, categorical_labels=True, normalize=True)
tflearn.data_utils.build_hdf5_image_dataset(datatest_file, image_shape=(32, 32), mode='folder', output_path=h5test_file, categorical_labels=True, normalize=True)

h5train = h5py.File(h5train_file, 'r')
X = h5train['X']
Y = h5train['Y']

h5test = h5py.File(h5test_file, 'r')
X_test = h5test['X']
Y_test = h5test['Y']
X, Y = shuffle(X, Y)
Y = to_categorical(Y, 10)
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, 10)
```

Comment: Could you please provide more detail of `to_categorical`?

Comment: I learned this from the guide of tflearn:Convert class vector (integers from 0 to nb_classes) to binary class matrix, for use with categorical_crossentropy. and the url is http://tflearn.org/data_utils/   @yixiao